# Unit test custom validators added to an Entity in Symfony 6.1 not working

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, validation, phpunit

I added 2 custom validators using (Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint) in a class.
But unit tests not passing.

For example:

```
use App\Validator as App Assert;
    class Person
    {
    #[App Assert\Person Exists(message: 'Person not found')]
    private ?string $person Id;
    
    #[App Assert\House Exists(message: 'House not found')]
    #[Assert\Not Null
    private ?string $house Id;
    }
```

Do you know how to write an unit test to validate a Person object $person ? Because I've tried several things but it's not working.

In my tests, I did something like this :

```
$person = new Person([
      'person' => 'non-existent-library-id',
    ]);

    $violations = $this->validator->validate($person);

    $this->assert Count(1, $violations);
    $this->assert Same('Person not found.', $violations[0]->get Message());
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why is there spaces in places there shouldn't be ? This code cannot work.

Comment: @Geek Have you written a UnitTest for your custom validators to be sure they work?